# Facebook API: check whether the current user likes certain page

Tags: facebook, api

I wonder if it is possible to know whether the user likes facebook page determined without using oauth and using javascript

Hi, I finally found the solution:

Simply make a GET to the following URL:

http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls=https://www.facebook.com/MyFacebookPage

Comment: Facebook does not allow “Likes Gates” any more.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. It was before but it is not allowed or possible anymore